# d = d + 1 inside a function with out a for loop (python)

Tags: python, function, matplotlib

So I am trying to make a simple program in python that uses matplotlib to plot some data. The problem is that I need the x-axis to incress by one each iteration. My code looks like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
d = -1
money = 40
def test ():
    for testing in range (5)
    ...
    ...
    ...
   plot(d,money)

def plot(d,money):
    d = d  + 1
   plt.plot(d, money, 'o')
```

The code works, but it plots all the data points on 0 of the x-axis, where as I would like it to plot the first point at 0, the second at 1, ect.

Thanks in advance for your time and help.

Edit: Basically I need a way so that in each loop d doesn't get reset to -1 but rather gets increased by 1

Comment: @Austin why use Import instead of import?

Comment: @NelsonGon, that was OP's code. We are not supposed to edit that part. You never know that's the problem or not.

Comment: Ah, I see. Makes sense.

Comment: Wrote  this on a phone it looks right now thanks

Comment: `plt.plot(list(range(1, len(money) + 1), money, 'o')` ?

Comment: object type of int has no len ()

Comment: Before `d = d + 1` add a new line `global d`

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using two lists, append the values in those lists and then finally plot them like this

```
def test():
    d = -1
    money = 40
    d_list = []
    money_list = []

    for test in range (5):
        ...
        d = d + 1
        d_list.append(d)
        money_list.append(money)
    plt.plot(d_list, money_list)
```

Comment: How is that a better solution?

Comment: This still leaves everything being plotted on 0

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a loop you could consider using arange if you know how you want your graph to increment. Such as

```
Import numpy as np
Import matplotlib.pyplot as plot

money = np.full(5, 40)
R = np.arange(0, 5, 1)

plot.plot(R, money)
```

Comment: I'm getting an error doing this: value error code and y must have same first dimensions, but have shapes (5, ) and (1, )